# SQL, Counting the user and grouping entry

Tags: php, sql, database

This is my db example

```
Employee Name 
charlie          
charlie          
jose             
jose             
jose             
john             
john
```

I want is to count the employees then store the counted number of employee as `entry` and store it into a new table in the database. I want to have this kind of output.

```
Employee Name | Entry
charlie           2
jose              3
john              2
```

Comment: This is a simple aggregation query?
just group by employee_name and count(entry)

Comment: I'm just a beginner in sql can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple query.

```
select Employee_Name,count(*) as entry from TableName
group by Employee_Name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregate function `count` and `group by` clause as :

```
select EmployeeName,count(*) from <<table>>
group by EmployeeName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sub-select query without Group by:

```
SELECT DISTINCT emp.name, 
       (Select count('x') from employee empSubQuery 
        WHERE empSubQuery.name = emp.name) as Entry 
from employee emp
```

Just an alternative answer. If there are proper indexes (Above the table, emp.name should have the index), MySQL will optimize this query and runs fine.